# Getting "502 bad gateway: request endpoint unable to handle" while validating the password

Tags: java, android, node.js

Am getting above error while validating the password in node.js and sending the response to android client.

Can anyone check  my validation code is correct or not?

```
var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
var Email =  queryData.email;
var Password =  queryData.passwd;
ibmdb.open(dbConnection, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        response.send("error occurred " + err.message);
    }
    else {
        console.log('before select');
        conn.query("SELECT PASSWORD FROM USER02130.USER_DETAILS123 WHERE SHORT_ID='"+Email+"'", function(err,  rows, moreResultSets) {
            if ( !err ) {
    var valid = rows.JSON();
    if (valid.PASSWORD==Password) {
            response.write("Successful login");
                                              }
    else {
       response.write("Invalid Password");
          }

}
else {
       response.write("error occurred " + err.message);
       }
       response.end();
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at this below link            http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm